# Can't add webpart to SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

On my sharepoint site I am unable to add an existing basic webpart to a page where I've added webparts before.  I am a site owner. I am using IE 8.  I also work remotely using VPN.

The strange thing is IE won't even open up the EDIT MODE.
When I use Google Chrome, it is able to open up EDIT MODE, and it was also able to open up the Add Web Part popup, but when you actually select a web part and press ADD...nothing gets added to the main page.

The extra strange thing is from Google Chrome, I am able to delete and modify existing webparts.

I've upgraded to IE 9 and the same issue still happens.

Answer (score 1):

i assume the similar issue you would be facing with firefox it seems your css is not compliant with IE8 try using ie8 in campatibility mode or use following querystring parameter at end of ur url 
toolpaneview=2 and see what is the result

Comment: Using IE9 with compatibility ON : I get a white screen that displays the text "Bad Request"   

Using Google Chrome: The screen goes into editable mode with a webparts panel browser on the right side.

Comment: In addition, from the work place using a different computer (not remote) - Using IE8: I was able to access the editable SharePoint fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem and it appeared that a CSS file was messing up with the Ribbon controls.

Try to disable a CSS file at a time.

Regards,

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue (or at least a very similar one) where, in edit page mode, clicking on 'Add a Web Part' had no effect. I was assuming that it is a JavaScript issue. In, I beleive, the same day, it effected both my Production and DEV Site Collections, in IE8, Firefox and Chrome. We restarted all of our servers and ran the config wizard. No good.

We were able to create new pages which seem to be uneffected.

For an existing page, our workaround is to edit the properties of the page, then, down at the bottom, select 'Open Page in Maintenance View'. Select one of the Web Parts and Close it. Note: It seems as though if you unselected the 'Allow Close' checkbox, it wont be on this list. Then click on the 'Go Back to Web Part Page'. Click on the zone where the closed Web Part was. You may now be able to 'Add a Web Part'. If so, the last Web Part folder on the left will be 'Closed Web Parts' which I beleive you can put back (Open) the closed Web Part.

Comment: Sharepoint is the worst framework ever! The company where I work choose this hell 4 years ago, every day I think in the possibility to ask resign

Answer (score 0):

I have see this issue occur when someone else has the current page open in edit mode. Until that person either checks in or undoes there checkout you will not be able to edit the page.